# Problem with using soul in paragraph mode and siunitx immediately after

Tags: paragraphs, siunitx, soul

This problem seems somewhat obscure, it is potentially a bug in `siunitx` or `soul` (I am aware of issues with the latter). Which one is uncertain and I'm not certain that it is a bug.

What I want to do is to highlight some text in paragraph mode and then have a number+unit (using `siunitx`) immediately afterwards.

Here is some code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\wibble}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

   \paragraph{\hl{Hello}} \SI{12}{\meter}

   \hl{Hello} \SI{12}{\meter}

   \paragraph{\hl{Hello}} a \SI{12}{\meter}

   \paragraph{\hl{Hello}} \wibble{12~m}

\end{document}
```

So here, I have tried a few things out. The top example is the malfunctioning one. Instead of highlighting the text, it writes "hl" before the argument of the macro. There are no malfunctions with the following cases:

- If not in paragraph mode (second example).
- If I put something else between the paragraph macro and siunitx (third example).
- If I use a different macro to `siunitx` after the paragraph macro (fourth
  example).

Comment: I suspect this is to do with the way `\paragraph` works in the standard classes (it is a sectioning command, but just dumps it's input directly under most circumstances). I need to review a few pieces of code: will have to be after work today!

Comment: For the moment you can add `\leavevmode` before `\SI`.

Comment: Cheers egreg, this temporary solution seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As observed by egreg, this behaviour is fixed by adding `\leavevmode` before `\SI`. The reason for this is that `\paragraph` is a sectioning command, but adds the argument to `\everypar` rather than printing anything. This means that if the `\SI` (or similar) command is the very first thing after the `\paragraph` then the section heading ends up printed inside the group which `\SI` starts. That is an issue here as `\hl` is used as a macro abbreviation by `siunitx` (for hectolitre), and so behaves incorrectly.

This is clearly not desirable behaviour, and so counts as a bug in `siunitx`. I will update the code, fixing this, later today and upload to CTAN. I'll post an update here once CTAN is updated.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I scooped the latest version (2.4j) of the your bitBucket repository and this has resolved the issue. I haven't been thorough though and checked if other things have changed. I'll close the issue.